# Introducing multiple foreign keys Throws error Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

My model class is like this

```
public class ProcedurePrice
{
    public int ProcedurePriceID { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public int ProcedureID { get; set; }
    public int InsuranceProviderID { get; set; }
    public int ProcedureCategoryID { get; set; }
    public int ProcedureSubCategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual InsuranceProvider InsuranceProvider { get; set; }
    public virtual ProcedureCategory ProcedureCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ProcedureSubCategory ProcedureSubCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual Procedure Procedure { get; set; }
}
```

Referenced Models,

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And so on....
Controller

```
public class ProcedurePriceController : Controller
{
    private readonly DiagnosisContext db = new DiagnosisContext();

    // GET: /ProcedurePrice/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IQueryable<ProcedurePrice> procedureprices =
        db.ProcedurePrices.Include(p => p.Department)
            .Include(p => p.InsuranceProvider)
            .Include(p => p.Procedure)
            .Include(p => p.ProcedureCategory)
            .Include(p => p.ProcedureSubCategory);
        return View(procedureprices.ToList());
    }  
}
```

This throws an error like this

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ProcedurePrice_dbo.InsuranceProvider_InsuranceProviderID' on
>   table 'ProcedurePrice' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I am new to MVC and Entity Framework, so no Idea on what's going on. Can anyone lend a hand here?

Comment: What the `ERF` is `ERF`..?

Comment: @spender Sorry, Entity Relation Framework

Comment: Unless we're talking about something different, the official title is Entity Framework, not Entity Relation Framework.

Comment: @spender Aaah, Thanks for correcting me, else I won't have  been noticing it for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify that when your entities are deleted, they should not cascade delete. Perhaps something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProcedurePrice>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.InsuranceProvider).WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // this is what you need
}
```

When you specify `ON DELETE CASCADE` for a foreign key in SQL, it means that when a principal row is deleted, all dependent rows should also be deleted. Sometimes the dependent rows may also be principals in other foreign keys, which means when they get deleted all of their dependents get deleted as well. This is what the error message means by "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths".

The above will tell EF that when a principal row is deleted, its dependents should not be deleted. Instead, if the principal row has dependents, the DELETE command will be rejected, and you will have to delete the dependents first.

Comment: I got little confused, Where I need to add this code? inside Controller?

Comment: @Athul the above override is in your derived `DbContext` class. It has nothing to do with the controller, this is all purely EF. Is your app database first, or model first? Who creates and upgrades the database, you or someone else?

Comment: Its code first approach, I Myself maintains the database. its a small application

Comment: How are you setting up the EF model configuration properties? Using Fluent API or Data Annotations?

Comment: I am new to EF, not sure about your question. This is the tutorial I am following
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I see. Do some searches on Entity Framework fluent API and Entity Framework data annotations. They are 2 different ways of modeling the relational database from your code. Very important information to know if you will be working with EF.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68729/discussion-between-athul-and-danludwig).